# Primefaces Mobile commandButton not working with ActionListener

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, actionlistener, primefaces-mobile

I presented the following problem.
when done click the button located in the dialog (pop -up ), the actionListener attribute does not work , ie not call the Backingbean.

The strange thing is that in the version PrimeFaces showcase this code works perfectly , only mobile fails.
Another curiosity is that the javascript function button is successful, what makes me think it's a problem of ajax for mobile version
Here the code

```
<pm:content>
    <h:form id="productForm">

        <p:dataList value="#{productoMB.productList}" var="pro"
            paginator="true" id="productDL">
            <f:facet name="header">Menu de comidas</f:facet>

            <p:panel header="#{pro.name}" style="text-align:center">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
                    <p:commandLink update=":homeFirst:productForm:productDetail"
                        oncomplete="PF('productDialog').show()" title="Ver Detalles">
                        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{pro.path}" width="320px"
                            height="120px" />
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{pro}"
                            target="#{productoMB.productSelect}" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:dataList>

        <p:dialog header="Detalle Plato" widgetVar="productDialog"
            modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
            <p:outputPanel style="text-align:center;">
                <p:panelGrid id="productDetail" columns="2"
                    rendered="#{not empty productoMB.productSelect}"
                    columnClasses="label,value">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:graphicImage library="images"
                            name="#{productoMB.productSelect.path}.jpg" width="100px"
                            height="100px" />
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value="Nombre:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{productMB.productSelect.name}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Precio" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{productoMB.productSelect.price}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Detalles:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{productoMB.productSelect.description}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Cantidad:" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{productoMB.quantity}" required="true">

                        <!--                        <p:ajax update="costo" listener="#{empMB.calcularPrecioTotal}" /> -->
                        <!--                        <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" maximum="200" /> -->
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:outputText value="Total a Pagar:" />
                    <!--                    <h:outputText id="costo" value="#{empMB.precioTotal}" /> -->
                    <p:commandButton value="Volver"
                        onclick="PF('productDialog').hide()"></p:commandButton>
<h:form>
                    <p:commandButton value="Agregar al carrito"
                        onclick="PF('carDialog').hide()" icon="ui-icon-cart" actionListener="#{productoMB.addCart}">

                    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>

        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
</pm:content>
```

This is a backingbean

```
package ar.com.as.presentation.mb;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import ar.com.as.business.bo.interfaces.GenericBO;
import ar.com.as.business.bo.patterns.FactoryFacade;
import ar.com.as.model.Cart;
import ar.com.as.model.Product;

public class ProductMB {

private List<Product> productList;
private Product productSelect;
private int quantity;
private List<Cart> cartList;

public ProductMB() {
    productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    cartList = new ArrayList<Cart>();
    findAllProduct();
}

public void findAllProduct() {
    GenericBO<Product> productBO = FactoryFacade.createFacade("facade")
            .getInstance().create("product");
    productList = productBO.findAll();
}

public void addCart() {
    System.out.println("se agrego al carrito");
}

// Getters+setters.

}
```

Any idea Como esta Problem solved .Or How to run the method addcart without ajax .
From already thank you very much .
Regards, Santiago

Comment: try marking your bean as `@ManagedBean` and `@SessionScoped` if you want to use carts

Comment: I'm using actionListener because it works in version showcase with ajax , but the mobile version of PrimeFaces not work.
What I need is to capture the event and handle Add to the backing bean

Comment: @user1928596 the bean is declared in the faces-config.xml friend, thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested h:form. Correct that, since it will very often (~always) lead to unexpected behaviour. Working in one environment and not in another is one of them.

[Related Stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nested+h%3Aform)

Comment: i have two form becouse  if i have only one form , the javascript function is unsuccessful

Comment: Two forms by itself is not a problem. Nested forms **are**... **always**. I posted the SO search for a reason. You have toredesign your page... and what javascript is not working without two forms?

Comment: thanks for coment , i think resolved the problem with <p:remoteCommand/ > and javascript starting success with one form

Comment: @BalusC, ahhh... sigh... luckily you can see revisions... Thanks. Santiago92: Care to post an answer with what it eventually became?

Comment: @BalusC Why to -1 to my question, what is wrong formulated ?
I was editing the code as I was trying things , so they can bring me some data , sorry if it bothers the editing ,
 I'm new here and I think it is a platform for constructive criticism .
Until now only criticism with comments you made to my question and not You provided no solution to it.
If you do not know , I ask please do not comment and ready. greetings Santiago

Comment: @BalusC Okay, I did not know that there was a way to edit questions.

Answer (score 0):

I share the solution I found to my particular problem is:

```
    <p:commandButton value="add" onclick="addC()"
                     icon="ui-icon-plus"
                     style="margin-left:20%; margin- rigth:15%" >
    </p:commandButton >
```

In the onclick call javascript function addC:

```
  <p:remoteCommand  name="addC"
                      actionListener="#{productoMB.addCart}" 
                      update="@widgetVar(cart)" />
```

RemoteCommand provides a simple way to execute backing bean methods with javascript.

Apparently mobile PrimeFaces has some bugs and does not work correctly with ajax.
Regards, Santiago